# What is the dimension of the following linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the dimension of the linear operator $T:C^3 \rightarrow C^3$ defined by $T(x,y,z)=(x+y,2x+2y,0)$?

I think it must be $2$.

Comment: Operators don't have dimension, do you mean rank?

Comment: rank T + nullity T = dim V

Comment: The dimension is a property of the vector space, not the operator.

Answer (score 2):

Since

$$T(x,y,z)=(x+y,2x+2y,0)=(x+y)(1,2,0)$$
so $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is spanned by $(1,2,0)$ and then $\mathrm{rank}(T)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

We have:$$T(1,0,0)\longrightarrow(1,2,0)\\ T(0,1,0)\longrightarrow(1,2,0)\\ T(0,0,1)\longrightarrow(0,0,0)$$
So: $$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 0\\
  1 & 2 & 0\\
  0 &0 &0 \end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 0\\
  0 &0 &0\\
  0 &0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$$ And so $$\dim(\text{Im}(T))=1$$

Comment: Needs a TU! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

v1= (1,1,0); v2= (2,2,0); v3= (0,0,0)
v2= 2v1 
so Dim(T)= 1

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This answer needs a lot of work.